# Generating graphs in Excel from CSV file

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I need to write a script that will create a graph based on data from two columns in a .csv file.

The data set:

```
Date, Memory Free
Thu Mar 28 12:19:03 ,19252852,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:08 ,19253444,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:13 ,19253492,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:18 ,19253676,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:23 ,19251164,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:28 ,19251568,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:33 ,19251496,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:38 ,19249448,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:43 ,19250472, 

Date, %Idle
Thu Mar 28 12:19:03 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:08 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:13 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:18 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:23 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:28 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:33 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:38 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:43 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:48 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:53 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:19:58 ,99.80,
Thu Mar 28 12:20:03 ,99.80,
```

This is what I have got so far:

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
'
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss"
Range("A1:B66677").Select
Range("A2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
    "'cwapp2_MemCPU-Date-pIdle'!$A$1:$B$66677")
End Sub
```

But it is not displaying the date in the x-axis. So how do I fix this? And, can I process multiple files using VBA?

Comment: While the macro recorder doesn't generate very good/general purpose code, it's a good place to start if you're not familiar with VBA and the Excel object model.  Record a macro while you insert a new graph into Excel after selecting a range of data.  Getting your data into Excel should be simple enough; tell it to open your CSV; that should be all it takes.  In fact, you should be able to get started by recording a macro as you do that manually too.  Once you have some code that almost works, post it here and describe any problems you're having with it.

Answer (score 0):

I clean up your code a little bit, and add a few lines at the bottom to set your tick labels for dates. This assumes the underlying data is a valid `Date` value recognized by Excel

The data you present in example is a string values that Excel does not interpret as date. If it is actually stored in CSV that way, let me know and we can tweak this a bit to fix that.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+p
Dim cht as Chart
Dim tl As TickLabels

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss"


Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
cht.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
"'cwapp2_MemCPU-Date-pIdle'!$A$1:$B$66677")

Set tl = cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels

tl.NumberFormat = "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss"

End Sub
```

To convert the string data in column A, you can use something like this:

```
Sub ConvertTextToDate()

Dim cl As Range
Dim dt As Date

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A66677")
        dt = Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 4)
        cl.Value = dt
        cl.NumberFormat = "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the date is actually being stored as a string. So I guess the way I formatted won't work.

Comment: OK. I'll add another procedure which will convert the values in column A to valid dates.

Comment: It is giving a type mismatch on:                                    dt = Right(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 4)

Comment: Can you debug what is the `cl.value`?